# How to Serialize and Deserialize Json with a .Text var

Tags: c#, android, json, mobile, xamarin.android

Hello I'm doing an applicative to android using Xamarin. I wrote a code to call an API from WSO2, the answer it returns depends on the ID the user send. It returns a JSON in the Content like this:

> {"consumerId":56704292158,
>   "categoryId":1,
>   "categoryDescription":
>   "Pessoa",
>   "firstName":"FN","lastName":"Last Name","fiscalDocuments":[{"fiscalDocument":{"documentType":"Brasil: nº CPF","cpf":199999992}}],"gender":"M","emailAddress":"r****@*.com","optIns":[{"optIn":{"brandName":"consul","acceptanceStatus":false}},{"optIn":{"brandName":"brastemp","acceptanceStatus":true}}],"communicationData":[{"communicationInfo":{"addressId":2****03,"phoneNumbers":[{"phoneNumber":{"phoneType":"mobilePhone","phoneNumber":5555555555}}],"streetAddress":"ANY
>   STREET","streetNumber":123,"streetComplement":null,"streetDistrict":"ANY TOWN","cityName":"ANY CITY","stateCode":"XX","zipCode":"12345","locationReferences":[{"locationReference":"Mercado"}],"countryCode":"ZZ"}},{"communicationInfo":{"addressId":2.563244E+7,"phoneNumbers":[{"phoneNumber":{"phoneType":"mobilePhone","phoneNumber":5555555555}},{"phoneNumber":{"phoneType":"homePhone","phoneNumber":555555555}}],"streetAddress":"ANY STREET","streetNumber":123,"streetComplement":"CASA","streetDistrict":"ANY TOWN","cityName":"ANY CITY","stateCode":"XX","zipCode":"12345","locationReferences":[{"locationReference":"Ao lado do deposito lua nova"}],"countryCode":"ZZ"}}]}

I just wanna get from this the fields firstName and lastName. I'm trying to serialize this but I think I'm doing something wrong. Here is the code

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using RestSharp;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Android.Util;
using App4.Resources;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace App4
{
    [Activity(Label = "App4", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        EditText edtcpf;
        Button btnConsumer;
        TextView txtcpf;
        RestRequest cpf { get; set; }
        public RestClient consumer { get; set; }
        IRestResponse mensagemConsumer;
        TextView txtresposta;
        RestClient orderId { get; set; }
        RestRequest requestorderId { get; set; }
        IRestResponse answer { get; set; }
        IRestResponse answerorder { get; set; }
        TextView txtnome;
        public string raika;
        private string teamname;
        private JToken primeironome;

       protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
       {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
            btnConsumer = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnConsumer);
            edtcpf = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.edtcpf);
            txtcpf = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtcpf);
            txtresposta = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtresposta);
            txtnome = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtNome);
            btnConsumer.Click += BtnConsumer_Click;

        }

        private void BtnConsumer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                // API Consumer CPF

                consumer = new RestClient("https://qa.api-latam.whirlpool.com/v1.0/consumers");
                cpf = new RestRequest("/" + edtcpf.Text, Method.GET);
                cpf.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                cpf.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer 70197e6c-d81b-384c-bb32-d69e8c10b101");
                mensagemConsumer = consumer.Execute(cpf);
                string nombre = Convert.ToString(mensagemConsumer.Content);
                Nome nome = new Nome();
                string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mensagemConsumer.Content, Formatting.Indented);
                nome.firstName = mensagemConsumer.Content;

                Log.Info("info ",json);
                txtresposta.Text = json;

                //API Consumer Appliances
                orderId = new RestClient("https://qa.api-latam.whirlpool.com/v1.0/consumers/");
                requestorderId = new RestRequest("/"+ edtcpf.Text+ "/service-orders", Method.GET);
                requestorderId.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                requestorderId.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer 70197e6c-d81b-384c-bb32-d69e8c10b101");
                answerorder = orderId.Execute(requestorderId);
                txtnome.Text = answerorder.Content;
                string respostaorder = Convert.ToString(answerorder);
                dynamic deserializado = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(respostaorder);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the class with get and set

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace App4.Resources
{
    public class Nome
    {
         public string firstName { get; set;}
         public string lastName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

How can I serialize and Deserialize this with a JSON that uses a var that depends on .Text like edtcpf.Text and its Content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I just wanna get from this the fields firstName and lastName.

For this request, you can install the [Newtonsoft.Json package](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) in your project and then for example:

```
TextView tvfirst = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.firstname);
TextView tvlast = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.lastname);

Button btn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btn);
btn.Click += (sender, e) =>
{
    var jsonstring = @"{'consumerId':56704292158, 'categoryId':1, 'categoryDescription': 'Pessoa', 'firstName':'FN','lastName':'Last Name','fiscalDocuments':[{'fiscalDocument':{'documentType':'Brasil: nº CPF','cpf':199999992}}],'gender':'M','emailAddress':'r****@*.com','optIns':[{'optIn':{'brandName':'consul','acceptanceStatus':false}},{'optIn':{'brandName':'brastemp','acceptanceStatus':true}}],'communicationData':[{'communicationInfo':{'addressId':'lalala','phoneNumbers':[{'phoneNumber':{'phoneType':'mobilePhone','phoneNumber':5555555555}}],'streetAddress':'ANY STREET','streetNumber':123,'streetComplement':null,'streetDistrict':'ANY TOWN','cityName':'ANY CITY','stateCode':'XX','zipCode':'12345','locationReferences':[{'locationReference':'Mercado'}],'countryCode':'ZZ'}},{'communicationInfo':{'addressId':2.563244E+7,'phoneNumbers':[{'phoneNumber':{'phoneType':'mobilePhone','phoneNumber':5555555555}},{'phoneNumber':{'phoneType':'homePhone','phoneNumber':555555555}}],'streetAddress':'ANY STREET','streetNumber':123,'streetComplement':'CASA','streetDistrict':'ANY TOWN','cityName':'ANY CITY','stateCode':'XX','zipCode':'12345','locationReferences':[{'locationReference':'Ao lado do deposito lua nova'}],'countryCode':'ZZ'}}]}";
    JToken token = JObject.Parse(jsonstring);

    var firstname = token.SelectToken("firstName");
    tvfirst.Text = firstname.ToString();
    var lastname = token.SelectToken("lastName");
    tvlast.Text = lastname.ToString();
};
```

I used two `TextView` to show the first name and last name item and use a button to parse the json string.

And by copying your json file, there seems to have a error in your json file with the node `addressId`, you can use some Json formatter to format your json string, then you can see the problem. I changed it to "lalala" for testing in my sample.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check if this is a valid json. According to my analysis it has some errors such as lastName. You can use this site to validate https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

This json was structured in a strange way, but by creating all the objects it has, you can use it like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace teste {
    class MainClass {
        public static void Main(string[] args) {

            var jsonString = @"{'consumerId':56704292158, 'categoryId':1, 'categoryDescription': 'Pessoa', 'firstName':'FN','lastName':'Last Name','fiscalDocuments':[{'fiscalDocument':{'documentType':'Brasil: nº CPF','cpf':199999992}}],'gender':'M','emailAddress':'r * ***@*.com','optIns':[{'optIn':{'brandName':'consul','acceptanceStatus':false}},{'optIn':{'brandName':'brastemp','acceptanceStatus':true}}],'communicationData':[{'communicationInfo':{'addressId':'2****03','phoneNumbers':[{'phoneNumber':{'phoneType':'mobilePhone','phoneNumber':5555555555}}],'streetAddress':'ANY STREET','streetNumber':123,'streetComplement':null,'streetDistrict':'ANY TOWN','cityName':'ANY CITY','stateCode':'XX','zipCode':'12345','locationReferences':[{'locationReference':'Mercado'}],'countryCode':'ZZ'}},{'communicationInfo':{'addressId':'2.563244','phoneNumbers':[{'phoneNumber':{'phoneType':'mobilePhone','phoneNumber':5555555555}},{'phoneNumber':{'phoneType':'homePhone','phoneNumber':555555555}}],'streetAddress':'ANY STREET','streetNumber':123,'streetComplement':'CASA','streetDistrict':'ANY TOWN','cityName':'ANY CITY','stateCode':'XX','zipCode':'12345','locationReferences':[{'locationReference':'Ao lado do deposito lua nova'}],'countryCode':'ZZ'}}]}";

            JsonSerializerSettings jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings {
                NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
                MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore
            };

            Pessoa pessoa = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Pessoa>(jsonString, jsonSerializerSettings);

            Console.WriteLine(pessoa.FirstName);
            Console.WriteLine(pessoa.LastName);
        }
    }

    public class Pessoa {
        public long ConsumerId { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string CategoryDescription { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public List<FiscalDocumentData> FiscalDocuments { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        public List<OptInData> OptIns { get; set; }
        public List<CommunicationData> CommunicationData { get; set; }
    }

    public class OptInData {
        public OptInInfo OptIn { get; set; }
    }

    public class OptInInfo {
        public string BrandName { get; set; }
        public bool AcceptanceStatus { get; set; }
    }

    public class FiscalDocumentData {
        public FiscalDocumentInfo FiscalDocument {get; set; }
    }

    public class FiscalDocumentInfo {
        public string DocumentType { get; set; }
        public long Cpf { get; set; }
    }

    public class CommunicationData {
        public CommunicationInfo CommunicationInfo { get; set; }
    }

    public class CommunicationInfo {
        public string AddressId { get; set; }
        public List<PhoneInfo> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
        public string StreetAddress { get; set; }
        public int StreetNumber { get; set; }
        public string StreetComplement { get; set; }
        public string StreetDistrict { get; set; }
        public string CityName { get; set; }
        public string StateCode { get; set; }
        public string ZipCode { get; set; }
        public List<Reference> LocationReferences { get; set; }
        public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    }

    public class Reference {
        public string LocationReference { get; set; }
    }

    public class PhoneInfo {
        public PhoneNumberInfo PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    }

    public class PhoneNumberInfo {
        public string PhoneType { get; set; }
        public long PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    }
}
```